# Ticketing server database security

Tags: mysql, security, database

I want to setup a ticketing system which will show the seats available instantly. However, for security, I do not want to open my database in internet. I want to setup a server which has public IP and contains the table need to be updated instantly. Then I will try to access this server through local network and updated my real database server. Is this method ok or there exist better method? For example, I have a server which have real IP, and I installed Mysql
database here and contains only three table that relate to seat information. When these three table is updated, then it will trigger to update the another full database tables in intranet.
I think this can prevent the real server from sql injection. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you are basically saying you want to have a database on a remote server for a ticketing system, but you do not want to expose that database connection to the Internet.  So you want to set a limited database online with the full database local to your machine?  And you will only update the remote database based on specific table data that you send from your local setup to your remote setup?

That sounds like a nightmare.

You should just have the whole database on the remote server, but secure it so only you can access it. You can either do this by limiting database port access via the firewall or by completely blocking access & using SSH tunneling to connect from remote.  I would recommend the SSH tunneling option since that is the easiest to setup & manage. [This article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/A_4205-MySQL-Workbench-Remote-Administration-using-SSH-to-Windows-Server.html) explains it best.